How can I delete specificsession data from datadog?
I was integrating Datadog in one of my projects for crash reporting and session tracking. Since, the project is currently in progress, I was looking to delete some of the dummy sessions from datadog.
Is there a way to delete the crash reports/sessions/logs from datadog?

You can't delete RUM sessions. My suggestion is to filter them out, similar to this question, or create a new RUM Application and client token for production vs testing.
